# How to get the battery level after connect to the BLE device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery, android-4.3-jelly-bean, batterylevel

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

And I want to get the battery level by using **Battery_Service** and **Battery_Level**.

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

    private static final UUID Battery_Service_UUID =
                UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private static final UUID Battery_Level_UUID =
                UUID.fromString("00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


    public void getbattery() {

        BluetoothGattService batteryService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(Battery_Service_UUID);
        if(batteryService == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery service not found!");
            return;
        }

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic batteryLevel = batteryService.getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
        if(batteryLevel == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery level not found!");
            return;
        }

         mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);
    　　　　　// What should I do that I can get the battery level ??
         Log.d(TAG, "Battery level " + mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel););
    }

}
```

But the value of `mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);` is not the battery level value

How to read the battery?

Comment: what value do you get?

Comment: the value of mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel); is "true"

Comment: sorry, I don't think I can help...  maybe this would:  http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=240110

Comment: heyy...could u please tell me how to get UUID,Major and Minor id of my ble device beacon ??I use the native code for ble device discovery from android developer site..

Comment: can you explain what this is? private static final UUID Battery_Service_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

Comment: @MarianPaździoch That is the BLE Service UUID of Battery Service

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

    private static final UUID Battery_Service_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    private static final UUID Battery_Level_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }


    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);   
        Log.v(TAG, "characteristic.getStringValue(0) = " + characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0));
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControl.EXTRAS_DEVICE_BATTERY, characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0));  
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void getbattery() {

        BluetoothGattService batteryService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(Battery_Service_UUID);
        if(batteryService == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery service not found!");
            return;
        }

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic batteryLevel = batteryService.getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
        if(batteryLevel == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Battery level not found!");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel);
        Log.v(TAG, "batteryLevel = " + mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(batteryLevel));
    }
}
```

When you call the function `getbattery()` , it will call `onCharacteristicRead`.
and `onCharacteristicRead` will call `broadcastUpdate` and transmit the characteristic and action to it.

And the `characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0)` in broadcastUpdate is the battery value of the BLE device.

Comment: It gives battery level as true.

Comment: @Wun @RajeshNarwal How did you get the `UUID`?

Comment: @M.S. Its a public service, defined in Bluetooth SIG site.
[See Here](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml)

Comment: @IronBlossom Where is UUID number written on the page? I can only see hexadecimal `0x180F`.

Comment: @IronBlossom Thank you. I wanted to know is UUID available online otherwise how would we find out base and battery level UUID?

Comment: The field name `BluetoothGattCharacteristic batteryLevel` is misleading here. It is not the actuall battery level...

Comment: Can you share full project of Heartrate monitor and Battery in single ble service

Comment: What if multiple BLE devices are connected? How can I know which device's battery level is being retrieved?